How exactly does the never miss portion of the "Boon of Combat Prowess" feat work?
I am anticipating fighting a monster that moves very fast without any of my spells as a level 20 cleric, so I'm trying to figure out what my options are.
One thing I'm considering is the epic feat "Boon of Combat Prowess" which has an effect that states:

Peerless Aim. When you miss with an attack roll, you can hit instead. Once you use this benefit, you can’t use it again until the start of your next turn.

Let's say I throw a rock at the monster, and they use the Teleport spell with a Readied Action to dodge it. Can I use the "peerless aim" portion of the feat, saying that if I roll to attack and miss, I can choose to hit instead. Would that cause the rock to home towards the target like a guided missile?

The attack resolves before the teleport can happen.
The rules for the Ready action state:

When the trigger occurs, you can either take your Reaction right after the trigger finishes or ignore the trigger.

If the chosen trigger is something like "I am attacked", then the reaction does not occur until the trigger, in this case the attack, has finished.

I'm not sure this is as cut and dry as you've definitively suggested. Can there be no triggers that would cause the attacker to either miss their attack or have it be denied?

@Pyrotechnical I can't think of any.

It depends on the description of the trigger
This question is similar to another from the 2014 rules and has a similar answer as well.
Readied actions need to have a 'perceivable circumstance' that will form the basis of them triggering.
For the scenario you've described, there are two ways that the trigger is likely to be phrased and it matters for this instance. The first might be:

Option A: If I am attacked/subject to an attack/take damage/etc., I will cast the Teleport spell to escape.

In this instance, the attack will simply resolve as normal and the features of the Epic Boon will ensure a hit in the event that you miss. Immediately after your first attack, the Teleport will trigger and no further attacks will be possible.
A second phrasing might be:

Option B: If I am being targeted by an attack/an enemy begins to attack me/a weapon is raised to strike me/etc., I will cast the Teleport spell to escape.

The phrasing on this is a little different and depends upon DM adjudication. Personally, I would allow this as I think someone raising a bow towards a target is a perceptible trigger and should be sufficient to trigger the Readied Action to teleport.
Notably, in this instance, the trigger happens before the attack roll ever occurs. Therefore, there is no opportunity for the Epic Boon's feature to help ensure a hit.
However, should the Teleport just be a short distance away, but still in range of the weapon, the attacker can simply adjust their aim and target the teleporting creature. Or attack another creature. Nothing about this Readied Action denies them their attack.
But what about [insert other triggers]
Any other permutations on how the trigger is defined will fall into the DM's adjudication. For example, if the trigger is:

Option C: When an arrow is flying towards me, I will cast Teleport to cause it to miss.

The rules don't really allow for such a scenario (i.e. once an attack roll is made, it's resolution occurs instantly). So the DM would have to adjudicate in some fashion, this answer suggests letting luck be the decider. I think that's fine, but honestly, I'm fine with anything the DM decides for this niche case. Some other options might be:

Make the caster have to succeed on a DC25 Perception check to actually observe the arrow soon enough to finish the spell.
Make the caster succeed on a DC25 Arcana check to time the completion appropriately.
Make the caster succeed on a DC25 Insight check to assess the attacker's intent in a timely fashion.

To be clear, there's not going to be a 'right' answer on this the way there might be with the other permutations on the trigger.
These rules would likely all be appropriate for the situation in either the 2014 rules or the 2024 rules, but for the the latter's inclusion of Epic Boons like the Boon of Combat Prowess in the PHB. For such a scenario, were I the DM, I might have such DCs in mind for scenarios that did not include this feat, but for a scenario where the attacker has this Epic Boon and the caster is attempting to be tricky with their Readied Action, I would not allow a roll (effectively ruling the DC impossible) and once the attack is loosed the caster is struck and then completes their Teleport (assuming concentration is maintained). This effectively forces them into Option A above because of how they phrased their trigger.
Again, this is strictly a DM adjudicating a scenario because the rules don't cover it.

The reaction may defeat your Peerless Aim.
Your enemy is clearly a homebrew creature which the rules don't directly cover. However, here's what the rules do say about this circumstance.
According to the Free Rules, a Readied action takes an action to set up, triggers on a perceivable circumstance, and occurs after that circumstance finishes. Monsters can also have Reaction abilities, which don't necessarily have these limitations. Frame challenge: You have to consider the possibility that your opponent will actually have the latter type of ability!
There's precedent for reactions having the potential to retroactively nullify a hit, even in the 2024 rules. For example, the warlock ability Investment of the Chain Master is triggered by taking damage, and lets you grant resistance to that same damage. The bard's Cutting Words lets you impose a penalty which can turn a hit into a miss, and the monk's Deflect Attacks can reduce damage after it's taken.
It's entirely possible that your enemy's teleport triggers on an attack which would hit, and the reaction is that he teleports away and the attack is nullified. Imagine if it was a melee rather than ranged attack: it would be ludicrous to assume you still hit an opponent who is out of melee range. Since you explicitly specify that his teleport can be used to dodge, we have to assume that it. I strongly suspect that the intent of Peerless Aim is that it's for turning a miss roll into a hit roll, not warping causality to allow your weapon to change direction in mid-air or teleport after the opponent.
Now, if it's a Readied Action to cast teleport, it's much weaker, because it arguably triggers after your atttack hits, and he'd have to argue that you can trigger after the attack hits but before it deals damage, which I don't think it a "perceivable" distinction. I don't think your enemy is actually using this, though, since they'd have to use up their action every turn to dodge you.
Consider also what the DM will do here. The intent of the enemy's ability is clearly that the opponent can react to dodge attacks which would otherwise hit. However, if I were the player character here, I would still argue to the DM, because they may accept the argument!

Do you allow 'feint' as a part of an attack? If so, then someone can absolutely have a readied action set to trigger on their perception of an attack. It would be triggered by a successful feint, and so would also be triggered when your attack action comes up and you say who you're attacking. The 'never miss' part might be hard to explain if you allow the teleport to take place first, but given the nature of reaction times &c, the easiest explanation is that the spell didn't take effect before the object actually struck them, so they take the damage and then teleport (or the rock is pulled through T-space with them and hits them where they teleported to... easy to explain if they teleport with all their gear). It's amusing to think of the rock homing in on them wherever they go, but ... well, maybe it's worth the comedy, but it makes for some hard to answer questions (what starts happening as the teleport gets farther away, etc.)

You appear to be referencing house rules which I don't think are applicable here as written. However, the rules you do cite were incorporated in an official capacity via the Inquisitive Rogue's Insight Fighting feature from Xanathar's.
